# GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM постоянно вовзращает положительное число

Tags: c++

GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM постоянно вовзращает положительное число, как мне сделать так чтобы я смог различить в какую сторону было повёрнуто колесо мышки?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    if (wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL) 
    {
        if (GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam) > 0) //постоянно возвращает положительное значение
            printf("mouse wheel up\n");
        else
            printf("mouse wheel down\n");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, очевидно, и не может работать. Если выполняется `wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL`, то сразу понятно, что `wParam` не может содержать никакой информации о том, на сколько повернуто колесо мыши. Применять к такому `wParam` макро `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM` бесполезно. Макро `GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM` предназначено для `wParam` обработчиков сообщений, а не для хуков.

Если вы пользуетесь хуком `WH_MOUSE`, то при `wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL` информация о повороте колесика получается так

```
const MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX *mhs = (const MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX *) lParam;
short delta = HIWORD(mhs->mouseData);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644969(v=vs.85).aspx

Если вы пользуетесь хуком `WH_MOUSE_LL`, то при `wParam == WM_MOUSEWHEEL` информация о повороте колесика получается так

```
const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *mllhs = (const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
short delta = HIWORD(mllhs->mouseData);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx