# Как узнать нажата XBUTTON1 или XBUTTON2?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Есть хук, который отслеживает нажатие WM_XBUTTONDOWN и WM_XBUTTONUP.  Мне необходимо понять какая именно боковая кнопка мыши нажата (1-я или 2-я). Использую следующий код.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_XBUTTONDOWN || wParam == WM_XBUTTONUP)
        {
            GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam); // result = 0
            MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX* mouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX*)lParam;
            mouseStruct->mouseData;// result = 0
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(myHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Но и GET_XBUTTON_WPARAM(wParam), и структура mouseStruct->mouseData возвращают 0.

Что я делаю не так и почему они возвращают всегда 0? Как исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему вы используете `MOUSEHOOKSTRUCTEX`? В обработчик `WH_MOUSE_LL` вам передается указатель на [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862795/get-wheel-delta-wparam-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE). Поэтому

```
const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *mouseStruct = (const MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
```

и вот там уже смотрим в `mouseData`.

Для `WM_XBUTTONDOWN` значения `XBUTTON1` или `XBUTTON2` должны передаваться в `HIWORD(mouseStruct->mouseData)`.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь он возвращает значение, не равное нулю. Но с чем его сравнивать в условии? Если сравнивать с XBUTTON1 или XBUTTON2, условие не работает (if (mouseStruct->mouseData == XBUTTON1)). Или я не с теми сравниваю?

Comment: А документацию читать?. Вам нужно смотреть в *старшее слово* `mouseData`. Именно в `HIWORD(mouseData)`.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Просто я новичок в С++, не всё знаю.

Comment: @Llirik 21: Я тоже об этом в первый-второй раз слышу, в первую очередь благодаря вам. И это не C++, а WinAPI. Все написано в документации.